# ScrollToTop in React Router

Tags: react-router

I've been following this scrollToTop function into my project
https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration

However, the result i get is that when i navigate to my route page, i initially still start from the bottom of the page but then i see a scrolling animation to the top. Is this how its supposed to work? I thought that the scroll up would be instantenous and i don't have the see the scrolling animation anymore.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
export default function ScrollToTop() {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, [pathname]);

    return null;
}
```

Return on my App

```
return (
    <Router>
       <ScrollToTop />
      <Route
        path="/"
        exact
        render={(props) => (
          <div>
            <Component1 = {Component1} />
          </div>
        )}
      />  
      <Route path="/games/:games" component={Content} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, managed to solve this by adding the 'behavior' option and setting it to 'instant'

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({left: 0, top: 0, behavior: 'instant'});
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```